# cannot see bin folder in fckeditor download

Tags: fckeditor

I tried to download fckeditor but there was no bin file containing any dll's after extracting the zip from: http://sourceforge.net/project/downloading.php?group_id=75348&filename=FCKeditor_2.6.4.zip

Am I being dense? Where is the bin file?

Answer (score 3):

FCKEditor is just Javascript and CSS files, the .NET integration is in [another package](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=75348&package_id=137125).

*Note you need the one you downloaded too.*

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the FCKeditor.Net WebControl. There is a separate download for this. See http://www.fckeditor.net/download.